# How can I use reactive .groupBy in RxGroovy

Tags: groovy, rx-groovy

I've got the following code in RxGroovy:

```
Observable
    .just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .groupBy({num -> num % 2 == 0})
    ...
```

And the type of `num` is `Observable<Integer>` instead of `Integer`. I believe the reason is that `.groupBy` exists in `Groovy` [by default](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.by/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-groupby-method.html). How can I still use reactive `.groupBy` method in RxGroovy?

Answer (score 0):

I should have explicitly stated the type, i.e., `.groupBy({int num -> num % 2 == 0})` solves the problem.